# Non-nested and overlapping hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Consider the following non-nested and overlapping hypothesis testing:
$$H_0:\;\theta\in A\quad vs\quad H_1:\theta\in B$$
where $A\cap B \neq \emptyset,\;A\not\subset B,\;B\not\subset A$.

Here, we have an estimator, $\hat{\theta}$, for the parameter of interest $\theta$ that is consistent under the both hypotheses.

In many textbooks, only likelihood base tests are intruduced. But, I have just an asymptotically normally distributed estimator.

Here, how can we test the hypotheses?

Comment: If there is substantial overlap between $A$ and $B$, $\theta\in B$ is not a suitable alternative. If $\theta$ is in both $A$ and $B$, you wouldn't want to reject $H_0$, would you? So $B\setminus A$ looks like a more suitable alternative, and would potentially allow for a likelihood ratio test (depending on details).

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thank you for the answer. However, that is my point: how can we deal with the overlapping null and alternative.